# Prove a closed set is a countable union of compact sets, in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: general-topology

I'm studying Sard's theorem and I want to know why is true that, in $\mathbb{R}^n$, every closed subset can be expressed as a countable union of compact sets.
Thank you, :)

Comment: If you denote $X$ your set, and $X_i=\{ x \in X : |x|<i \}$, then $X_i$ are compact (closed and bounded) and $$X= \bigcup_i X_i$$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider $\bar{B}(0,n)$, the closed ball with center $0$ and radius $N$. If $C$ is a closed set, consider
$$
C_n=C\cap\bar{B}(0,n)
$$
Then $C_n$ is a closed subset of $\bar{B}(0,n)$, which is compact, hence $C_n$ is compact. Obviously
$$
C=\bigcup_{\substack{n\in\mathbb{N}\\n>0}}C_n
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! 